# Pulling Marketo Data to S3 using Airflow

Tags: python, airflow, marketo

I am looking for a process to pull Marketo data using Airflow. It seems that Airflow has no native Marketo webhook, did I understand that correctly ?

Or is there a way to use an existing Airflow operator/webhook to pull data from Marketo?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most Operators for 3rd parties just wrap around APIs, Marketo has a [REST api](https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/). You could use a `PythonOperator` with `requests` pull your data.

An example DAG could be:

```py
import pendulum
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.s3 import S3CreateObjectOperator


@dag(
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=pendulum.yesterday(tz="Europe/London"),
    catchup=False,
)
def marketo_api_dag():
    @task.virtualenv(system_site_packages=False, requirements=["requests"])
    def pull_from_marketo():
        import requests
        import json

        response = requests.get()  # pull from marketo API using requests
        return json.dumps({})  # response formatted how you need it

    marketo_api_response_data = pull_from_marketo()

    save_marketo_to_s3 = S3CreateObjectOperator(
        task_id="save_marketo_to_s3", s3_bucket="s3bucket", s3_key="/path/to/save", data=marketo_api_response_data
    )

    marketo_api_response_data >> save_marketo_to_s3


marketo_api_dag_run = marketo_api_dag()
```

- requires the [Amazon provider](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/index.html) `apache-airflow-providers-amazon`.